# Is the univalence axiom injective?

Tags: agda, cubical-type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Is the univalence axiom invertible (modulo paths)? Is it possible to prove, using [Agda's Cubical library](https://github.com/agda/cubical/), to prove the following:

```
open import Cubical.Core.Glue

uaInj : ∀ {ℓ} {A B : Set ℓ} {f g : A ≃ B} → 
  ua f ≡ ua g → equivFun f ≡ equivFun g
```

I suspect the above should hold, because in example 3.19 of [the HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/), there is a step in the proof where an equivalence between two equivalences is used to prove the equivalence between their functions:

> [...] so `f` is an
>   equivalence. Hence, by univalence, `f` gives rise to a path `p : A ≡ A`.
>
> If `p` were equal to `refl A`, then (again by univalence) `f` would equal the
>   identity function of `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, `ua` is an equivalence, so it's injective. In the HoTT book, the inverse of `ua` is `idtoeqv`, so by congruence `idtoeqv (ua f) ≡ idtoeqv (ua g)` and then by inverses `f ≡ g`. I'm not familiar with the contents of cubical Agda prelude but this should be provable since it follows directly from the statement of univalence.

Answer (score 1):

To put [András's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53303310/477476) into code, we can prove injectivity of equivalency functions in general:

```
equivInj : ∀ {ℓ₁ ℓ₂} {A : Set ℓ₁} {B : Set ℓ₂} (f : A ≃ B) → 
  ∀ x x′ → equivFun f x ≡ equivFun f x′ → x ≡ x′
equivInj f x x′ p = cong fst $ begin
  x , refl                   ≡⟨ sym (equivCtrPath f (equivFun f x) (x , refl)) ⟩
  equivCtr f (equivFun f x)  ≡⟨ equivCtrPath f (equivFun f x) (x′ , p) ⟩
  x′ , p ∎
```

and then given

```
univalence : ∀ {ℓ} {A B : Set ℓ} → (A ≡ B) ≃ (A ≃ B)
```

we get

```
uaInj : ∀ {ℓ} {A B : Set ℓ} {f g : A ≃ B} → ua f ≡ ua g → equivFun f ≡ equivFun g
uaInj {f = f} {g = g} = cong equivFun ∘ equivInj (invEquiv univalence) f g
```

The only problem is, [`univalence` is not readily available](https://github.com/agda/cubical/issues/9) in the `Cubical` library. Hopefully that is getting sorted out shortly.

**UPDATE**: In reaction to the above bug ticket, [proof of univalence is now available in the `Cubical` library](https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/abe298b85f2ac4fa2933ca1ed4bb125e18fdd1a5/Cubical/Basics/Univalence.agda#L54).